# Adobe Flex Huge Image Issue

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am trying to load an image of size 6000 × 8192 pixels which cleary exceeds flash platform limitation for an image.

I am trying  which doesn't seem to work.

I have had search around the internet and found few components like BitmapDataUnlimited, and BigAssCanvas but I amn't sure if I can use them for displaying a remote image as none of them seem to have a working implemented example and just the class itself.

Any advice on this will highly be appreciated.

Regards

Katherine

Comment: Well, for FP11, the limit is gone. See: http://www.bytearray.org/?p=3216 `Enhanced high resolution bitmap support — BitmapData objects are no longer limited to a maximum resolution of 16 megapixels`

Comment: Hi Jacob. I know that's true for FP11 but with FP11 still in beta and it's release date unknown, I was wondering if there is a solution for FP10?

Comment: Can I ask why you need such a big image? Is there a reason you can't tile the image or scale it appropriately?

Comment: I am getting the image in form of XML from an external client so whatever cropping etc I have to do has to be done via Flex. I tried scaling the large image after Complete event fires on the image but even after i scale it to say 1024 x 768, i can't still see the image

Answer (score 1):

It makes a difference which FlashPlayer you are targetting:

versions VS maximum bitmapsize

flashplayer -9 : 2880x2880 px
flashplayer 10 : 4096x4096 px
flashplayer 11 : unlimited